# How to replace several parts in a url with a regex?

Tags: node.js, regex, url, replace

I am using regex to replace some parts of an URI.

What I would like to do is, for example, in a URI: `/something/more/and/continue/123456789/word?l=1`

1. replace `/something/more/` by an `'_'`
2. replace the `'/'` but only the one before `'and'` and after `'more'`
3. replace `/word?` by `'&'`

I have tried to do this with groups but it hasn't worked.

Is that possible to do it all at the same time or in another way?

Comment: You could match with 3 groups, and use replace with a callback to do the replacements per  group.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Could you give an example?

Comment: I have added an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example match the first part and capture 2 parts, and in the replacement function check for the group values and do the replacements.

```
(?:\/[^\/]+){2}(\/[^\/]+)([^?]*)\/\w+\?
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:\/[^\/]+){2}` Repeat 2 times matching `/` and 1+ times any char except `/`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\/[^\/]+` Match `/` and 1+ times any char except `/`
- `)` Close group 1
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^?]*` Match 0+ times any char except `?`
- `)` Close group 2
- `\/\w+\?` Match `/` 1+ word chars and `?`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hpEj3u/1)

You can start the replacement with `_` as `/something/more/` is matched and is not in a group.

Then you can handle group 1 and group 2 and concatenate the string.

```js
let s = "/something/more/and/continue/123456789/word?l=1"
const regex = /(?:\/[^\/]+){2}(\/[^\/]+)([^?]*)\/\w+\?/;
console.log(s.replace(regex, (_, g1, g2) => {
  let s = "_"
  if (g1) s += g1.replace(/\//g, "");
  if (g2) s += g2 + "&";
  return s;
}))
```

Comment: Nice, I think it is exactly what I want.
I wanted just to ask you if you could explain step by step this: `(\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+)(\/[^\/]+)([^?]*)\/\w+\?` and the other regex?

Comment: @ack31 I will add an explanation of the pattern.

Comment: @ack31 I have updated the answer with an explanation and updated the code a bit.

Comment: @ack31 Yes I think so, you are free to implement the code for your requirements.